# Apply dataset as Broadcast in Spark

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, broadcast

I have two datasets, and i need to register one dataset(smaller one) as Broadcast when trying to register i am anable to use broadcast functions.

Here is the code:

```
JavaRDD<String> maps = ctx.textFile("C:\\Users\\sateesh\\Desktop\\country.txt");
Broadcast<JavaRDD<String>> broadcastVar = ctx.broadcast(maps);
//Broadcast<Map<Integer, String>> broadcastVar = ctx.broadcast(map);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(9);
JavaRDD<Integer> listrdd = ctx.parallelize(list);
JavaRDD<Object> mapr = listrdd.map(x -> broadcastVar.value());
System.out.println(mapr.collect());
```

Here I am not able to get `broadcastVar.value().get(x)`. If iregister any manual map as broadcast its works well, but in case of text files it doesn't works.

Comment: `Broadcast<JavaRDD<String>> broadcastVar = ctx.broadcast(maps.collect());` ?

Comment: Thanks, working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to broadcast any data to cluster it **has to be from driver**. So, `collect()` your `rdd` and broadcast it.

```
JavaRDD<String> rdd = ctx.textFile("C:\\Users\\sateesh\\Desktop\\country.txt");

Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastVar = ctx.broadcast(rdd.collect());
```

> Please be aware `collect()` will bring entire `rdd` to driver it might throw OOM exception. Broadcast is suggested for less sized data.

Comment: Can we collect rdd as rdd.collectAsMap?
or any other way to convert to map insted of list?

Comment: `rdd.collectAsMap` also fine.

Comment: `rdd.collectAsMap` is available for `PairRDD`s only.